# Android: AudioRecord and DynamicsProcessing

Tags: android, audio-recording

Currently I am recording audio using [`AudioRecord`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord), and I want to implement EQ, compressor and limiter audio filters. that [`DynamicsProcessing`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/audiofx/DynamicsProcessing) is just what I need, but the key thing is that it typically supposed to work with [`MediaPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) or [`AudioTrack`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/AudioTrack), which means that the effects are applied during playing the already prerecorded audio sample.

But what I need is to apply these filters during recording, so that the resulting file will contain already filtered audio.

Is it possible to achieve this using [`DynamicsProcessing`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/audiofx/DynamicsProcessing) and somehow binding it to the [`AudioRecord`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) instance? Or are there some other ways to apply such a filters during audio recording native to SDK or using some existing library?

P.S.: I couldn't find anything relevant and the only idea that came up is implementing the filtering of the data gained via [`AudioRecord#read`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord#read(short[],%20int,%20int)) by hands, which, I believe, will take quite a while for a person that isn't familiar with audio engineering.

Comment: how did you end up implementing this?

Comment: @tenprint man, that was years ago... I don't remember anything about that project, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **No**.

You can't attach the DP effect to the `AudioRecord` through `SDK API`.

Look at the `Sound Amplifier` app, it deployed `DynamicsProcessing` features but **re-implementing** it with a standalone shared native library.